# Integrate google-ad-manager with ios framework

Tags: ios, admob, ios-frameworks, google-ad-manager

I'm trying to add google ad manager to custom iOS framework.
I'm testing this framework with a test app, and make the dependencies by Cocoapods.

If I'm adding the adMob account id to the test application info.plist seems like everything works as expected.

But if I'm adding the adMob  account id to the framework info.plist, I'm getting an error:

**GADInvalidInitializationException - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GADInvalidInitializationException', reason: 'The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized without an application ID.**

Is what I'm trying to do possible? or everyone who's wanted to use my framework will be need to added my adMob id to their info.split?
[You can see the implementation and the design with this project](https://github.com/apester-dev/ios-sdk/tree/feat/MED-269/cocoapod-init)